# Keep WordPress Related posts without plugin inline

Tags: php, css, wordpress

I am running a blog on WordPress and want my single posts to show related posts, but without any plugin. I have added following codes to the bottom of the single page -

```
<div class="relatedposts">
<h3>Related posts</h3>
<?php
  $orig_post = $post;
  global $post;
  $tags = wp_get_post_tags($post->ID);

  if ($tags) {
  $tag_ids = array();
  foreach($tags as $individual_tag) $tag_ids[] = $individual_tag->term_id;
  $args=array(
  'tag__in' => $tag_ids,
  'post__not_in' => array($post->ID),
  'posts_per_page'=>4, // Number of related posts to display.
  'caller_get_posts'=>1
  );

  $my_query = new wp_query( $args );

  while( $my_query->have_posts() ) {
  $my_query->the_post();
  ?>

  <div class="relatedthumb">
    <a rel="external" href="<? the_permalink()?>"><?php the_post_thumbnail(array(150,100)); ?><br />
    <?php the_title(); ?>
    </a>
  </div>

  <? }
  }
  $post = $orig_post;
  wp_reset_query();
  ?>
</div>
```

But they are showing in vertical line whereas I want to display them inline horizontally in a row. You can see them in the below screenshot 
[Related posts vertically shown](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SvP64.png)

So kindly help me to figure out the issue so that I could Keep WordPress Related posts without plugin inline. thank you so much in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You can define `.relatedthumb` as a flexbox.

```css
a {
cursor: pointer;
}
.relatedthumb {
display:flex;
justify-content: flex-start;
}
```

```html
<div class="relatedposts">
  <h3>Related posts</h3>
  <div class="relatedthumb">
    <a><img src="http://lorempixel.com/75/100" /><p>Dummy text</p></a>
    <a><img src="http://lorempixel.com/75/100" /><p>Dummy text</p></a>
    <a><img src="http://lorempixel.com/75/100" /><p>Dummy text</p></a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: But I am not using a custom one. I am fetching them through tags. I have thousands of posts So need a universal way. thanks for the answer.